# How to launch a .vbs or Window powershell every time my application like notepad, esclipe starts

Tags: powershell, vbscript, window, registry, alternate-data-stream

how to launch a *.vbs every time my application like notepad, esclipe starts. so that i dont have to every time i start my esclipse , go and click on vbs manually
Also i dont want to put them in start up , coz i have to run the script every time my either notepad  starts.

Will WMI events polling be of any help?custom event
or 
Alternative data stream!! the issue with alternative data stream is it will launch one application at a time either my vbs or my notepad. i want both+ 
or
Can registry be of a any help?

*OS: Window 7 32 and 64 bit both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an event listener and launch your vbs file when notepad starts:

```
Register-WmiEvent -Class Win32_ProcessStartTrace -SourceIdentifier ProcessStart -Action {

    $proc = $event.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent

    if($proc.ProcessName -eq 'notepad.exe')
    {
        wscript "C:\test.vbs"
    }

}
```

Comment: i  have copy pasted this code in event.vbs  but getting compilation error at 1st line character 20.+ do i need to run this script every time i restart computer?

Comment: You need to run this script in PowerShell.

Comment: Thanks, but every time i restart my system i have to run this again.!! I wanted to figure out is it possible the script self invoke ,or is invoked along  when i am doing my normal work like opening a notepad?.Clearly , i think so i need an event to invoke the script , hence i thought let it be starting a new process like notepad. anyways i am doing a click to open the notepad, let that click  run this as well?

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/12/08/use-a-powershell-module-to-work-with-wmi-permanent-events.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use a .bat/.cmd that starts the .vbs and the .exe (in an order you prefer).

Or - on second thought - why not incorporate the starting of the .exe into the .vbs?

Comment: :"incorporate the starting of the .exe into the .vbs"-- here issue remains the same , which is 1) i dont want to manually run my vbs/Powershell script 2)i dont want to run it on system start up 3) should run only when i have clicked on notepad

Comment: For parent .bat ,again it doesn't have the intelligence to self invoke, itself. then i have to make effort to  click on bat file each time my system has restarts.

Comment: @user2303800 - I understand that you want to click just once and don't want to start a monitoring script. Then starting the .vbs (and letting it run notepad.exe and/or eclipse.exe/.bat automagically) would give you just this 'one click to start working'. Same holds for the 'click once to start the .bat that run the other programs' strategy.